# Web SQL get column list from table

Tags: javascript, regex, sqlite, google-chrome, web-sql

I try get column list from Web sql (Chrome local database).
Оne of the decisions - get info from sqlite_master

```
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name = "'+name+'";
```

For example i get this result

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
number INTEGER unique, description TEXT, password TEXT, url TEXT )
```

So help me write regex for get column names, or, maybe, show me another simple way get column names.

PS. i dont wont to do `select * from table`... for getting columns names. I think this is bad solution..

Comment: select name from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(N'table_name')

Comment: are you sure this query for the web sql?

Comment: No, I'm not sure, as this is for sql server..

Comment: To get the table create syntax (useful for reviewing the columns, but not that usable as part of a codebase) you can do ```SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = 'your_table_name' AND type = 'table'```

Answer (score 4):

To get the columns of a table, execute `PRAGMA table_info(table_name)`:

> [PRAGMA table_info()](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info)
>
> Return a single row for each column of the named table. The columns of
>   the returned data set are:
>
> - cid:        Column id (numbered from left to right, starting at 0)
> - name:       Column name
> - type:       Column declaration type.
> - notnull:    True if '`NOT NULL`' is part of column declaration
> - dflt_value: The default value for the column, if any.

Unfortunately, Chrome blocks all `PRAGMA`s, so this doesn't work in WebSQL.

---

In WebSQL, you can access only tables that were created by your app, so you should just remember which columns your tables have.

---

Alternatively, you can just try to read from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1
```

With the `LIMIT` clause, this will be very efficient because you read only some random record. (Except if you have some very big blob in that record.)

Comment: PRAGMA table_info(my_table)
could not prepare statement (23 not authorized)

Comment: about SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1;
problem begin when table is empty.

Comment: In WebSQL, you can access only tables that were created by your app, so you should just remember which columns your tables have.
----------------------------------
Yes I understand. I write own small ORM library. I make, that table automaticly created by model and drop or add column, if I change property of model. Now i refactor my code and seeking an more elegant solution

Comment: `you should just remember which columns your tables have.`  UNACCEPTABLE.  My web app works on my entire sub-domain.  This completely breaks my "generic SQL table" app for browsing tables, which *requires* being able to introspect tables another app in the same domain created.  +1 though for answering my question of WTF Chrome was giving me the "not authorized" garbage.

Answer (score 3):

In chrome, this worked for me with [html5sql](http://html5sql.com/). I also made a codepen that uses pure-HTML5 with a cool Promise-based query function, [here](http://codepen.io/konsumer/pen/yyNJEr/?editors=001).

```
function getDB(cb){
    html5sql.process("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name NOT LIKE 'sqlite\\_%' escape '\\' AND name NOT LIKE '\\_%' escape '\\'", function(txTables, rsTables, tables){
        if (!tables.length) return cb(null, []);
        tables.forEach(function(table){
            var s = table.sql.split(',');
            s[0] = s[0].replace(new RegExp('create\\s+table\\s+' + table.name + '\\s*\\(', 'i'),'');
            table.fields = s.map(function(i){
                return i.trim().split(/\s/).shift();
            })
            .filter(function(i){
                return (i.indexOf(')') === -1)
            })
        });
        cb(null, tables)
    }, cb);
}
```

This will hit your `(error, tables)` callback like this:

```
[{
    "type": "table",
    "name": "Users",
    "tbl_name": "Users",
    "rootpage": 6,
    "sql": "CREATE TABLE Users(\n  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n  firstName VARCHAR(255),\n  lastName VARCHAR(255),\n  email VARCHAR(255),\n  created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (DATETIME('now','localtime'))\n)",
    "fields": [
        "id",
        "firstName",
        "lastName",
        "email",
        "created"
    ]
}]
```

Note the `fields` section. This works, even if there are not records. The regex/string parsing could probably use some improvement, and you could probably grab type-info with it too, but this seemed to work with all my usecases. An alternate method once you know the fieldnames, in SQL:

```
SELECT TYPEOF(id) as id, TYPEOF(firstName) AS firstName , TYPEOF(lastName) AS lastName, TYPEOF(email) AS email, TYPEOF(created) AS created FROM Users;
```